# Upgrading Kernel

Tags: custom-roms, kernel

I am somehow confused about the kernel and how it plays out. I have a couple of questions:

1. Let's assume my device kernel reports its kernel as 3.0.8 (using uname -r). How can I figure out what configuration my kernel was build with?
2. If I get the latest linux kernel code (or any version above my current one) from its website and build it with my desired config, can I just replace my kernel only? If so, how?